# Flutter some time app not going to close on double tap

Tags: flutter

here i am using double tap app close function ! when i use multiple screens and get back my main page that time this functionality nothing works....! it shows me toaster on single tap...(warning for exit) and again i click on it ! it goes back to screen ! please some one look into

```
DateTime currentBackPressTime;
Future<bool> onWillPop() async{
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
if (currentBackPressTime == null ||
    now.difference(currentBackPressTime) > Duration(seconds: 2))  {
  currentBackPressTime = now;
  Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: "Press One More Close The APP",
      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
      gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
      timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
      backgroundColor: Color(0xfff58634),
      textColor: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 16.0
  );
  return Future.value(false);
}
return Future.value(true);
}

   @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomPadding : false,
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset : false,
  body: WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: onWillPop,  /// here is back button for exit
    child: (_isLoading) ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) : Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 70,left: 16),
                child: GradientText(
                  gradientDirection: GradientDirection.ltr,
                  type: GradientType.linear,
                  text: 'Log In',
                  colors: [HexColor("#ED443D"),HexColor("#F07844"),HexColor("#A15BA3"),HexColor("#A05AA2"),],
                  style: GoogleFonts.nunito(fontSize: 38.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may no longer be at the bottom of the routing stack, you need a plugin that does not depend on routing, it is very flexible and simple

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_close_app

I recommend this library to you. It is very flexible and simple. It does not depend on routing navigation. App can be closed on any page. It supports the following functions:

- ✅ Press back 2 times to close app

  - ✅ Custom time interval
  - ✅ Customize the prompt message
  - ✅ Customize matching conditions
  - ✅ Support Android
- ✅ One click to close app

  - ✅ Support iOS
  - ✅ Support MacOS
  - ✅ Support Windows
  - ✅ Support Linux